# What is the usage of 子 in 「修我戈矛，与子同仇」?

Tags: classical-chinese

This particular phrase comes from《诗经·秦风·无衣》

Full: 岂曰无衣？与子同袍。王于兴师，修我戈矛。与子同仇！

Answer (score 3):

Translation:

Who said that you have no clothes to wear,

I will share with you my robe.

The king has called upon us that,

we make ready with spears and Ge's (戈)，

we fight against our enemies.

Comment: Can it be correct to interpret the 于 as 對我們?

Comment: "于" serves as an auxiliary verb here. Its exact meaning has lost AFAIK. My guess is that it indicates a present continuous tense, as in "黄鸟于飞 (a yellow bird is flying)" （also from 《诗经》）。So maybe a better translation is "... The king is calling upon us that ...".

Answer (score 1):

子是对男性的敬称，here it means "you".

In your quote 与子同仇，it means

> （我）与你同仇敌忾

Similarly, we call 孔仲尼 as 孔子 to show respect. Also we have 庄子、墨子、孟子、老子……